# Running DotNet exe from another DotNet EXE which is running from schedule task

Tags: c#, windows

I have created a DotNet console EXE called Monitor.exe. This Monitor.Exe launches two DotNet console EXEs. I want to make sure that Monitor.Exe is always running on the server therefore, I have setup a schedule task and calling Monitor.Exe through a Bat file. When the schedule task runs it execute Monitor.Exe in the background and its not able to launch the other two EXEs. But if I directly run the Batch file it launches a CMD window and runs the Monitor.Exe which in turns start other two EXEs.

Is there any way that I can schedule the Monitor.Exe in scheduled task to run in foreground. I want to schedule it in a way that logging to server is not required.

Please suggest.

Comment: why do you need a bat file in the first place ? you can schedule taskscheduler to run your master exe (Monitor.exe)

Comment: Sounds like what a better implementation would be involved around creating a service (`monitor`) to execute as the logged-in user.  Honestly, this appears to be an X/Y problem.  We'd do better understanding what you're trying to accomplish, than to try and solve through the method you're presenting.

Answer (score 0):

Considering both your child exes are console based and does not have any UI based actions.

Have you tried the below

```
StartButton > Task Scheduler > Basic Task > Path to your Monitor.exe
```

Additionally, you can also customize its Triggers and Conditions.